# finding the points where a complex function is differentiable (Need guidance)

Tags: complex-analysis

Recently I have encountered the topic on complex differentiation and i had these two questions

$f(z) = (z+5)/(z-5i) + (z-5)^10$
and
$f(x+iy) = (6x+y^2) + i(5xy+y)$

What I had to do was to determine every point that the functions can be differentiated and also provide them with the formula for the derivative.

I have been reading through lectures notes and websites but I still don't understand the theory behind how to actually determine where the points are and differentiate them. can anyone provide any hints and guides on how to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first function is given in terms of $z$. It has a reasonable algebraic form: it's a rational function. You may remember from calculus that rational functions are differentiable at every point of their domain. The same is true in complex analysis, and for the same reasons:

- the linear functions $f(z)=az+b$ are differentiable, with $f'(z)=a$ (check using the definition)
- the sum of differentiable functions is differentiable
- the product of differentiable functions is differentiable (and there is a product rule for derivative)
- the quotient of  differentiable functions is differentiable, as long as denominator is not $0$.

Since a rational function is constructed by the above means, it is differentiable at every point where the denominator is not $0$. Of course, when the denominator is $0$, it's not even defined, so definitely not differentiable. This should give you enough to deal with the first $f$.

---

The second $f$ is given in terms of $x$ and $y$, not in terms of $z$. In terms of $x$ and $y$, it is a polynomial, which implies that it has continuous partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$. There is a theorem that says that if such  a function satisfies the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), then it's complex differentiable. Here $u= 6x+y^2$ and $v=5xy+y$. So, you should find the derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$, put them into the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and see if they term into equalities. It looks like   $u_x=6$ and $v_y=5x+1$; these are equal only when $x=1$. Also, $u_y=2y$ and $v_x=5y$; when does $u_y=-v_x$ hold? and you have the *only* point on the plane where $f$ is complex differentiable.