# Differential function in $ \mathbb C $

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers

I have to find the points where the function $f$ given by

$$f(z)=(-5+5i)z^2+(14+2i)\vert z \vert^2+(-5+5i) \bar z^2$$

is differentiable and to calculate the differential in those points.

Now as f has the form of polynomial then f is differentiable in every point of $ \mathbb C $.

So $f'(z)=2az-2bz^{-3} \vert z \vert^4$, where $a=(-5+5i)+(14+2i)$ and $b=(-5+5i)$ .

Is my solution correct??

Comment: Note: I've use the property $\vert z \vert ^2$=z $ \bar z$

Comment: Just write $f = u + \Bbb i v$ and $z = x + \Bbb i y$ and use the Cauchy-Riemann relations.

Comment: according to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465958/finding-the-points-where-a-complex-function-is-differentiable-need-guidance I think my method is correct because my function f(z) has the form of the first function (from the link) @AlexM.

Comment: If you are asking about complex differentiability (as opposed to real differentiability), then your solution is wrong. In particular, $f$ is not a polynomial function of a complex variable (it is only a polynomial map of two real variables). Once again: impose the Cauchy-Riemann relations and find out the $z$ where they hold.

Comment: @AlexM. ok Cauchy-Riemann equations then

Comment: @AlexM. the algebra gets a little complicated, do you think would be easier if I use Cauchy-Riemann equations in it's polar form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$f(z)=(-5+5i)z^2+(14+2i)\vert z \vert^2+(-5+5i) \bar z^2$$

Then:

$$f(a+bi)=(-5+5i)(a+bi)^2+(14+2i)(a^2+b^2)+(-5+5i) (a-bi)^2$$
$$=(-5+5i)(a^2+2abi-b^2)+14a^2+14b^2+2ia^2+2ib^2+(-5+5i) (a^2-2abi-b^2)$$
$$=(-5+5i)(2a^2-2b^2)+14a^2+14b^2+2ia^2+2ib^2$$
$$=-10a^2+10b^2+10a^2i-10b^2i+14a^2+14b^2+2ia^2+2ib^2$$
$$=12a^2i-8b^2i+4a^2+24b^2$$

So $f(a, b)=u(a, b)+iv(a, b)$, where $u(a, b)=4a^2+24b^2$ and $v(a, b)=12a^2-8b^2$.

Notice that:

$$\partial_a u(a, b)=8a$$
$$\partial_v u(a, b)=48b$$
$$\partial_a v(a, b)=24a$$
$$\partial_b v(a, b)=-16b$$

By the Cauchy Riemann equations, $f$ is differentiable at $a+bi$ if and only if $8a=-16b$ and $48b=-24a$, and these equations hold if and only if $a=-2b$. Therefore $f$ is differentiable at the points $-2x+xi$ $(x \in \mathbb R)$ and $f'(-2x+xi)=\partial_a u(-2x, x)+\partial_a v(-2x, x)i=-16x+24xi$.

Please recheck.

Comment: this question was in my exam (two days ago) and I solve it but I conclude that f is differentiable only at 0 point. 

Comment: Aw, that happens :/ I rechecked my calculations and unfortunately it looks like they are ok.

Comment:  ..thanks anyway my friend.

Comment: @AnneliseToft, I noticed that we are both from the same town. Are we from the same university?

Comment: mmh I don't think so. I mean I'm from São Paulo but I'm not living there anymore since I started the university. I'm studying in Mexico.